# How do you safely free memory?

Tags: c, valgrind, free

The code given below is giving undefined behaviour, sometimes the code runs well, but sometimes it gives a `munmap_chunk` error.

```
char *str = "hello world";
if(str != NULL) free(str)
```

Is there something wrong I am doing in the above code ?

Also how to avoid `duplicate free` ? How do I check if the variable has some memory right now / or has not been freed before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the string literal ("hello world") will be stored in the data section, in a read-only page.

So you can not free them.

**Also how to avoid duplicate free ?**

free() will free pointed memory but will not make pointer as NULL.After every free() make pointer as NULL.

```
if(str != NULL)
{
 free(str);
 str = NULL;
}
```

Comment: That's a false good advice. First, `free(NULL)` is legal and valid, second, you are only *hiding* a double free. A program that relies on such a piece of code has broken logic.

Comment: A program that relies on such a piece of code has broken logic. ..? i am not understanding this. Please explain?

Comment: If you find yourself in a program where you don't know how many times a chunk of memory has been freed (such as in your case), then your logic is wrong. Memory should be freed *exactly once*. Setting the pointer to `NULL` in order to prevent the memory from being freed *again* is a design problem.

Answer (score 2):

That string wasn't allocated with `malloc()`, so it shouldn't be freed with `free()`.  String literals are allocated statically in your executable, not dynamically at runtime.

Comment: I see. And what about the answer to my second question ?
  How to avoid duplicate free?

Comment: To avoid calling free() again...after each free() mask pointer as NULL so you will not go to free them again...i have explained in my answer

Answer (score 0):

`char *str = "hello world";
if(str != NULL) free(str);`

It is wrong, `*str` is not malloced. and "hello world" is stored in read only memory, you can't free it